# How can I debug my AngularJS application with WebStorm if it is served by a server other than WebStorm?

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, javascript-debugger

Imagine I use the following gulp task to serve my website:

```
gulp.task("server", ['build'], function () {
    $.util.log($.util.colors.green("Server started at http://localhost:" + 4000));
    server.listen(PORT);

    open("http://localhost:" + PORT);
});
```

and here is the server code:

```
server.get("*", function(req, res){
    var base = __dirname + "/dist";
    var path = base + decodeURIComponent(req.path);
    console.log(path);
    try{
        var stat = fs.lstatSync(path);

    }
    catch(e){
        res.sendFile('index.html', { root: base });
        return;
    }
    if(stat.isFile())
        res.sendFile(path);
    else{
        res.sendFile('index.html', { root: base });
    }
});
```

I wanted to know how can I use the WebStorm debugger for my application?

Comment: Try the Chrome extension ~ https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/configuring-javascript-debugger-and-jetbrains-chrome-extension.html

Comment: @Phil I installed the extension and in webstorm I set the port number to 4000, but I get 404 generated by webstorm.

Comment: what port number did you change? the one in `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger`? Please make sure to set it back to default (63342). These settings have absolutely nothing to do with the port your Node server is listening on.
Port in `Settings | Buiild, Execution, Deployment | Debugger` is the port  used by Chrome debugger in order to connect to IDE. Setting it to your Node.js server port will break client-side debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to debug - your angular application, or the server it's hosted on?
To debug your server-side code, you need using **Node.js** Run configuration (see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/05/guide-to-node-js-development-with-webstorm/, https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Running+and+debugging+Node.js+application#RunninganddebuggingNode.jsapplication-DebuggingNode.jsapplocally)

To debug client side, you have to create **JavaScript Debug** run configuration, specify the URL of your Node.js server (`http://localhost:4000`, or whatever it is), add remote URL mappings (if necessary) - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2022.2/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html#debugging_js_on_external_web_server

Comment: thanks for your answer, I want to debug my client side code.

Comment: the page @lena shared is behind a login. no one would have a similar link ? (My licence  account don't give access to this confluence page).

Comment: I've updated the link, please see the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Go to Run/Debug Configurations and setup a new Gulp configuration right in WebStorm. This can be found under Run > Edit Configurations...

After you've setup the configuration, just click debug (Run > Debug or Shift + F9) once you have that configuration selected.

This is available to us in IDEA and PyCharm, so I assume it's available in WebStorm. You might need to install the Gulp plugin, but I did not for IDEA.

[image]

Comment: Ok, that image is way larger than I intended it to be, sorry for the HUGE screen capture.